# Inserting Group Section inside another Group Section of Crystal Report?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I am creating crystal report in which the fields are grouped by its record serial number. And this group is wholly grouped by its name.

Like:

```
    Group Header #1 (Record Name)
      Group Header #2 (Serial No)
        Details (the individual records)
      Group Footer #2
    Group Footer#2
```

Let me explain the problem. I have 10 records under the each record name. The values of 10 records of each record name are interlinked and that is why ,i am grouping it by serial no.

The Problem is that the records are not grouped by its name. Once the first record entry is completed, i need the second record to start from first. But the second record continues with the first.

I cant understand the working of this groups.

Could someone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Malar, When you say completed what do you mean?

If 'completed' is a flag in your data, perhaps you can manipulate using this, if you require help with this let me know.

Comment: @Telexx I means, once the entry for first record is over, i need the second record to be started from first. but it interlinks with the value of first record.

Comment: "Once the first record entry is completed, i need the second record to start from first. But the second record continues with the first." This line is confusing, Please give an example.